# Wie sagt man "breaking point" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Wie kann ich "breaking point" auf Deutsch ausdrücken?

Ich gebe ein Beispiel an, das die gewünschte Bedeutung einfängt:

> I wonder if the republicans have a breaking point with Trump's antics.

Kann jemand mir helfen, diesen Satz zu übersetzen?

Comment: *Ich frage mich, ob die Republikaner, was Trumps Mätzchen betrifft, eine **Schmerzgrenze** haben.* Das ist das im Deutschen übliche Bild. Du kannst vor *eine* noch ein *überhaupt*, *noch* oder *überhaupt noch* einfügen, um deine Verwunderung auszudrücken.

Comment: Ist breaking point wirklich gemeint, im Englischen gibt es auch pain barrier?

Comment: @Janka und Thomas, im Englischen gibt es ein "pain threshold", aber diese hängt gewöhnlich mit Verletzung zusammen, zum Beispiel, wieviel Schmerz man ertragen kann. Kann man "Schmerzgrenze" auch im diesen Sinn benutzen?

Comment: *Schmerzgrenze* deckt alles ab, selbst den Preis beim Runterhandeln – obwohl immer behauptet wird, Deutsche würden nichts runterhandeln. Der psychische *breaking point* ist im Deutschen *der Zusammenbruch* (auch: *der Nervenzusammenbruch*), allerdings passt dieses Bild in deinem Beispielsatz nicht.

Comment: @Mark Ich habe im Wiktionary nachgeschaut und der breaking point ist in der Tat die Schmerzgrenze in deinem Sinne, mehr dazu in der Antwort.

Comment: @Mark Are you a native English speaker to approve the common use of breaking point as used in your sentence? Or do you have references, quotations?

Comment: @Janka Ich habe nachgeschaut und es scheint wirklich die im Deutschen übliche Schmerzgrenze zu sein, Wiktionary zitiert dazu die New York Times: "Even before Hurricane Sandy, New York was sheltering more homeless people than any city in the United States: a record 47,000 women, men and children, in a system strained to the breaking point."

Comment: In diesem letzten Beispiel könnte man aber wieder *bis zum Zusammenbruch* übersetzen. Es kommt immer auf das Bild an.

Comment: Was IMHO im gleichen Sinne ist, also der Punkt an dem einer oder mehrerer Aktionen eine Reaktion folgt. Egal ob Zusammenbruch oder offene Kritik oder entsagende Unterstützung.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I am a native English speaker. "Breaking point" is common to use as in the example I provided, as well as the example that Janka provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eine mögliche Form, das im Deutschen auszudrücken, wäre auch:

> Ich frage mich, wo der Punkt ist, ab dem die Republikaner Trumps Irrlichterei  **nicht mehr mitmachen**.

Das wäre allerdings eher eine lockere mündliche Ausdrucksweise. Ein bisschen gediegener und daher auch im Schriftlichen verwendbar:

> Ich frage mich, wo der Punkt ist, ab dem die Republikaner Trumps Possen  **nicht mehr mittragen**.

Noch etwas freier:

> Ich frage mich, ob es einen Punkt gibt, wo die Republikaner dem Trump wegen seiner ewigen Sperenzchen **den Laufpaß geben**.
>
> Ich frage mich, ob es einen Punkt gibt, wo Trump mit seinen Eskapaden den Republikanern **endgültig zu weit geht**.

Und hier noch weitere rein mündliche Varianten:

> Ich frage mich, wo der Punkt ist, ab dem die Republikaner Trumps Faxen  **dicke haben**.
>
> Ich frage mich, wo der Punkt ist, ab dem die Republikaner Trumps Zicken  **satt haben**.
>
> Ich frage mich, wo der Punkt ist, ab dem die Republikaner Trumps Flausen  **über haben**.

Übrigens geht es auch recht nahe am *breaking point*, allerdings halt nicht als Substantiv sondern als Verb (*brechen mit*):

> Ich frage mich, ob die Republikaner wegen seiner Marotten **mit** Trump irgendwann **brechen**.

Answer (score 11):

Es werden wohl am häufigsten folgende Begriffe benutzt:

> Schmerzgrenze, Belastungsgrenze, Toleranzgrenze

Eine gute Aussage würde also wie folgt formuliert werden können:

> Ich frage mich, ob die Republikaner eine Schmerzgrenze für Trumps
>   Mätzchen haben.

Schmerzgrenze definiert sich in diesem Sinne also als der Punkt, an dem ein grenzwertiges Verhalten nicht mehr toleriert wird.

Comment: Als weitere Variante würde ich "Sollbruchstelle" nennen.

Comment: @userunknown Republikaner mit Sollbruchstelle? Nein, das ist was leicht anderes. Das wäre eine *absichtlich eingebaute Obergrenze*. Und "Bruch" bedeutet: Da geht was kaputt, anstatt dass man einfach anfängt, gegenzusteuern.

Comment: Doch, German Language SE ist genau dazu da, bei der Übersetzung von Phrasen und Redewendungen ein möglichst präzises deutsches Pendant (oft in Abhängigkeit vom Kontext) zu finden. Und, umgangssprachlich ist die *Schmerzgrenze* auch nicht. Ich habe mir erlaubt, das aus deiner Antwort zu entfernen.

Comment: @Takkat Danke. Nicht einfach die Grenzen zu ziehen, aber ich lerne. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: leider sind die Grenzen ein bisschen schwammig, das macht es nicht leichter. Wir arbeiten dran!

Comment: *Schmerzgrenze für Trumps Mätzchen* hört sich für mich stilistisch nicht sauber an, da würde ich Jankas Vorschlag *Schmerzgrenze, was Trumps Mätzchen betrifft* vorziehen, auch wenn es etwas länger ist.

Comment: @tofro: Für das Beispiel passt Sollbruchstelle nicht, dafür ist es bei anderen Gelegenheiten besser.

Comment: Wie wäre dieser Satz: "Haben Republikaner eine Belastungsgrenze bei Trumps  Mätzchen " ?

Answer (score 5):

Eine weitere Möglichkeit:

> Ich frage mich, ob den Republikanern nicht irgendwann wegen Trumps Possen der Geduldsfaden reißt.

Bei dieser Übersetzung wird wie im Original suggeriert, dass etwas kaputt geht (bricht oder reißt).